# How to make a connection to RabbitMQ which is installed in Linux

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am getting an error 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable' when trying to connect to rabbitmq which is installed in Linux and my application is docker supported.Anyone knows how to make the connection to rabbitmq or how to solve the aforementioned error??

Comment: "how to solve the aforementioned error" do some basic network troubleshooting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This means the client is not able to reach the server. Try find out if RabbitMQ port is exposed to the host (check open ports with netstat).

```
netstat -an
```

If the port is not exposed via Docker, you could do something like this:

```
  ports:
    - 5672:5672
    - 15672:15672
```

If it is exposed I would check if you can connect to the port with netcat or telnet. If this doesn't work, it's likely a firewall within Linux.

If all ports accessible, ensure you have the right connection. You should be using port 5672 or at least where Rabbit MQ server is running. 15672 is the HTTP API port and management UI.

> Note that the UI and HTTP API port — typically 15672 — does not support AMQP 0-9-1, AMQP 1.0, STOMP or MQTT connections. Separate ports should be used by those clients.

**Connection string:**

```
{  
   ….  
  "Rabbit-MQ-AMPQ": "amqp://[username]:[password]@21.72.175.25"  
  ….  
}
```

You could try not specify a port and see what happens as well.

**Sample:**

```
/* 
using RabbitMQ.Models; 
using RabbitMQ.Client; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; 
using System.Text; 
*/  
 public void Produce(string message)  
        {  
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()  
            {  
                Uri = new Uri(configuration["Rabbit-MQ-AMPQ"])  //Through DI
            };  
  
            using (var conn = factory.CreateConnection())  
            {  
                using (var channel = conn.CreateModel())  
                {  
  
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "messages_share",  
                                durable: false,  
                                exclusive: false,  
                                autoDelete: false,  
                                arguments: null);  
  
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);  
                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",  
                                         routingKey: "messages_share",  
                                         basicProperties: null,  
                                         body: body);  
  
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);  
                }  
            }  
  
        }
```

**Disclaimer:** Check your RabbitMQ server configuration and also understand the nature of what is being done to confirm the port.

Comment: Thanks for the response...But it didn't work for me. I have the rabbitmq URL  with HTTP protocol but my application refers to the endpoint as 'amqp' protocol ... is that the issue??

Comment: So the rabbit MQ port is exposed to the host OS? Can you provide more *detail* on what you done and your configuration? You can add it to the question to help us help.

Comment: Yes. the port is exposed. The rabbit MQ is installed in Linux and it's dockerized. Suppose "http://21.72.175.25:15672" is the rabbit MQ URL, and the connectionfactory parameter has the endpoint of  "amqp://21.72.175.25:15672".

Comment: is it required to enable amqp protocol for the rabbitMQ URL?

Comment: Note that the management UI and HTTP API port — typically 15672 — does not support AMQP 0-9-1, AMQP 1.0, STOMP or MQTT connections. Separate ports should be used by those clients.

Comment: Okay. Have you meant this issue would not solve if I am using port 15672? should I host to another port...?

Comment: Updated answer. Does that help?